# Adding Section and Getting Error: Invalid update: invalid number of sections

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm working on a challenge by Big Nerd Ranch to create app that adds random items separated into 2 sections. When there are no items it should display "No Items".

At initial stage I've set it up to have a single section with header "No Items" and upon adding item it needs to get updated to two sections with titles "50 AND UNDER" and "OVER 50".

When adding item, I'm getting this error thrown at `tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)` inside the `addNewItem` method.

I can't make out the source of the error - while debugging I can clearly see that once the `addNewItem` is triggered, sections is updated to 2, then as part of the flow of adding a new row (calling `tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)`) it updates the `numberOfSections` and `numberOfRowsInSection` but then errors out prior to entering `cellForRowAt`. So it appears that all of the prerequisites are updated properly in order to actually add the row content.

Full code for ViewController below or at GitHub [link here](https://github.com/yanichik/iOS-BigNerdRanch/tree/iOS/LootLogger_Challenges/chapter9/Silver).

> Thread 1: "Invalid update: invalid number of sections. The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (2) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (1), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted). Table view: <UITableView: 0x141012c00; frame = (0 0; 393 852); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600003648840>; backgroundColor = <UIDynamicSystemColor: 0x600002d61240; name = tableBackgroundColor>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600003817400>; contentOffset: {0, -59}; contentSize: {393, 110}; adjustedContentInset: {59, 0, 34, 0}; dataSource: <LootLogger.ItemsViewController: 0x140106ab0>>"

ItemsViewController:

```swift
import UIKit

class ItemsViewController: UITableViewController {
    // add ItemStore property to have access to store that holds all items
    var itemStore: ItemStore!
    var sections = 1

    @IBAction func addNewItem(_ sender: UIButton){
        let newItem = itemStore.createItem()
        sections = 2
        if newItem.valueInDollars > 50 {
            if let index = itemStore.itemsOverFifty.firstIndex(of: newItem){
                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 1)
                tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            }
        } else {
            if let index = itemStore.itemsFiftyAndUnder.firstIndex(of: newItem){
                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
                tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func toggleEditingMode(_ sender: UIButton){
        if isEditing{
            sender.setTitle("Edit", for: .normal)
            setEditing(false, animated: true)
        } else {
            sender.setTitle("Done", for: .normal)
            setEditing(true, animated: true)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        if sections == 1 {
            return "No Items!"
        }
        else if section == 0 {
            return "50 AND UNDER"
        } else {
            return "OVER 50"
        }
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if sections == 1 {
            return 0
        } else {
            if section == 0 {
                return itemStore.itemsFiftyAndUnder.count
            } else {
                return itemStore.itemsOverFifty.count
            }
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "UITableViewCell", for: indexPath)
        let item = indexPath.section == 0 ? itemStore.itemsFiftyAndUnder[indexPath.row] : itemStore.itemsOverFifty[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = item.name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "$\(item.valueInDollars)"

        return cell
    }

    // Override to support editing the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            let item = indexPath.section == 0 ? itemStore.itemsFiftyAndUnder[indexPath.row] : itemStore.itemsOverFifty[indexPath.row]
            itemStore.removeItem(item)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }
    }

    // Override to support rearranging the table view.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt fromIndexPath: IndexPath, to toIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        itemStore.moveItem(from: fromIndexPath.row, to: toIndexPath.row)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your table starts out with 1 section with 0 items. In that case you show the section header of "No Items!".

The first time that `addNewItem` is called, you suddenly act as if the table view always had 2 sections and you add the new item to either section 0 or 1 as needed. This is where the table view throws the error. Before your attempt to insert 1 row in one of the two sections, the table thinks it has 1 section with 0 rows. After you insert one row into a section, you claim the table view has two sections. But you never told the table view to add the 2nd section.

You need to rewrite the logic of `addNewItem` to add the new section the first time you add a new item.

```swift
@IBAction func addNewItem(_ sender: UIButton){
    let newItem = itemStore.createItem()
    if (sections == 1) {
        // Tell the table about the new section and reload the first
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        sections = 2
        tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: 0), with: .fade)
        tableView.insertSections(IndexSet(integer: 1), with: .fade)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    } else {
        // The table already knows there are two sections, add the new row as needed
        if newItem.valueInDollars > 50 {
            if let index = itemStore.itemsOverFifty.firstIndex(of: newItem){
                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 1)
                tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            }
        } else {
            if let index = itemStore.itemsFiftyAndUnder.firstIndex(of: newItem){
                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
                tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Depending on what you want, you might need reverse functionality when deleting rows. If you delete the last item and you want to show "No Items!" again, you will need to remove section 1 and reload section 2 while resetting `sections` back to 1 from 2.

---

Unrelated to your question but worth pointing out - you do not need your `toggleEditingMode` method nor the button you added for it. Instead, use the built in edit button provided by `UIViewController`. This assumes your table view controller is in a `UINavigationController`.

In `viewDidLoad` you can add:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
}
```

`editButtonItem` is provided by `UIViewController`. It supports toggling the view controller between "Edit" and "Done" and it calls `setEditing(_:animated:)` for you. Very simply and easy.

Comment: HangarRash: that works. What is the purpose of `tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: 0), with: .fade)` if section 1 already exists and it is not being updated in any way at this point? If the first add ends up going to section 1 it should just add a row with `tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)`

Comment: You do not need to call `insertRows` for the very first row since that will be handled by either the call to `reloadSection` or `insertSection`. You want to call `reloadSection` on the first section to at least get the new section header. It will also add the new row if it belongs to the first section.

Comment: HangarRash: with regard to deletion of last row, I would assume I need to delete section 2 and reload section 1. Your way works but just wondering why - it's counterintuitive because it seems more efficient (in a stack) to just pop the last, but here we are removing the first and shifting

Comment: You need to delete section 1 and reload section 0. What is counter intuitive? Regarding the insert or the delete? What I'm suggesting for the delete is only if you wish to revert back to showing "No Items!" once all rows have been removed.

Comment: I just assumed the sections are held in some sort of stack/array so performance-wise it would be better to pop instead of shift when removing sections.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "pop" and "shift". There's insert, delete, and reload. That's it.

Comment: I would probably just reload the whole table when you go from 1 section to 2 and vice-versa.

Comment: @Paulw11 That certainly works too but then the OP wouldn't have learned anything :)